# django apache + nginx ssl for admin part

Tags: django, apache, ssl, nginx

I want to make my django /admin/ urls to be ssl secured. And i have my site running in apache mod_wsgi. But i was suggested to configure SSL in nginx configuration.

```
#/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
worker_connections  1024;
# multi_accept on;
}
http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;
tcp_nodelay        on;
gzip  on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

So i have nginx.conf, i think it is a place to place ssl part. **Where do i have to place it? And what additional configuration should i do to make it work.**

I found that code. But no idea where to place. **I don't have my site conf in sites-available.**

```
server {

        listen   443;

        ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/certs/myssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/private/myssl.key;

        server_name domain1.com;
}
```

Comment: this is not very clear. you say you have your site running on apache/mod_wsgi but then you talk about nginx/ssl. Do you have nginx handing off to apache over a local connection? If so please add this information. The main part of your question does not seem to be related to Django per se, instead you seem to be asking where you should put your nginx configuration files. What do you mean by "I don't have my site conf in sites-available."? The nginx configuration you have shown so far is not nearly sufficient for a running site. Is there more?

Comment: Yes, exactly. client->nginx->apache.

Comment: Which version of nginx do you use? Do you have sites-enabled/ dir in /etc/nginx/ ? If yes - there is a sample host defined, just add the listening port and SSL files to it and it should work.

Comment: thanks. i'll try. One more question. If i want to hide not the whole site but /admin/ part behind ssl, what should i add?